# Host Named Site Collections with own Content DB, and problems (Top Nav Bar, and force to log on always)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, content-database, top-link-bar, host-named

This is the scenario:

1. All Site Collections have their own Content Database
2. Site Collection A is Root Site Collection (created directly under Web Application = has exact same url as Web Application scA.domain.com). It is not Host Named Site Collection
3. Site Collection B is Host Named Site Collection and its url is scB.domain.com
4. I have my own `TopNavigationBar` with static nodes (manually added to it) and deployed by a empty SP item and a web scoped feature.

Following is the script to create the Web Application:

```
New-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool $appPool -ApplicationPoolAccount $appPoolAccount -Name $name -DatabaseName $dataBaseName -Url $url -Port $port -HostHeader $hostHeader -AuthenticationMethod "Kerberos"

$app = Get-SPWebApplication "http://$hostheader"
$app.BrowserFileHandling = "Permissive"
$app.Update()
```

Site Collection A created by following:

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name $dbName -DatabaseServer $dbServer -WebApplication $webAppUrl | out-null

New-SPSite -Url $url -OwnerAlias $domainAnduser -Name $name -Template $template -Language 1053 -ContentDatabase $dbName
```

Site Collection B created by following script:

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name $dbName -DatabaseServer $dbServer -WebApplication $webAppUrl | out-null

$wapp = Get-SPWebApplication $webApplicationName

New-SPSite -Url $url -OwnerAlias $domainAnduser -HostHeaderWebApplication $wapp -Name $name -Template $template -Language 1053 -ContentDatabase $dbName
```

Now My problems:

1. for All Site Collection I need to log on always everytime I browse to them
2. When I browse to Site Collection B (Host Named one) it generates following error. it seems that it uses another Web.Config file or something.

> System.Web.HttpException: The SiteMapProvider 'MyTopNavMapProvider'
>   cannot be found. at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.get_Provider()

Thank you for your help I appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to login because probably you use NTLM and due to using Host-Named SC the browser considers it as a totally different web, due to different Host Header (or domain!).
2. For the 2nd aspect you need to give us more context, it might be due a cross-domain security issue, but honestly is a shot in the dark.

Comment: ok, Thanks I can survive with the first problem. but about the second problem what do you need to know more? now I made some more tests. It seems that it is not the content db that create the problem becuase I created a MangedPath based SC with own database and it worked perfeclty. so it seems that it is the Hos-Named issue that causes problem. I created a public class which implements PortalSiteMapProvider and manually I have created childNodes. Used an empty SP Item with a element, squence=30 and ... to replace the topNav in v4.master and a web scoped feature contains that empty sp item.

Comment: I solved the problem number 2 by adding host header to all host-named Site collections for the web application. Is there any better solution?

Comment: actually, the Web Application that is supposed to have Host-Named Site Collections should NOT have host header in IIS at all, simply use Computer Name or LB Ip. But I believe initial setup has not probably taken care of this upon creation

Comment: can you please help me to solve the problem without having host headers in IIS? What I only want to do is showing my top navigation bar. I created it by creating a public class which implements PortalSiteMapProvider an overriding its GetChildNodes, adding 4 static SiteMapNode in the SiteMapNodeCollection and return it. created an empty SP element to override the delegate control, id=TopNavigationDataSource, sequence=30 and properties among others Name="ID" topSiteMap, SiteMapProvider=MySiteProvider. and using a web scoped feature to deploy this, added this feature to my onet.xml(webtemplate).

Comment: q: are you trying to actually show cross site collections sites??

Comment: Yes, I want to show site collection where ever I am. the problem is it works only for path-based site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Registry Key 'disableloopbackcheck' with value 1 under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0 .. It ll disable log on everytime you browse.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/scottstewart/archive/2014/09/15/disableloopbackcheck-when-routing-through-a-load-balancer-powershell-sample-included.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do not use hostheader webapplication with host named site collections. This is not supported.